# how to achieve "contains" for numeric field using caml in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I want to achieve a wildcard search in CAML Query. I used the "Contains" clause to achieve this functionality for text field. I want to achieve the same functionality for a numeric field. Contains does not work for it. Can someone tell me how to achieve this functionality for a numeric field. Is there any operator such as "like" in SQL???

Comment: Just so I understand.... If you have a numeric value 49785, you want to be able to search on 78 and have 49785 returned as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAML only allows contains to be used on Text or Note type fields. But you could set up a new calculated list column (type text) who's value is the same as the number.

Then, use your CAML query on the "text" field that Contains the numerical string.

~ED